# Deserialise JSON containing numeric key. Json.NET

Tags: c#, json

I want to deserialize the  JSON (using Json.NET) to an object. But can't, because the class name would need to begin with a number.

```
{
"status":"ok",
"meta":{
       "count":1
},
"data":{
       "7887207":{
           "global_rating":9524,
           "statistics":{  
               "random":{
                    "damage_dealt":54395747,
                    "wins":17502,
                    "hits_percents":74,
                    "battle_avg_xp":797,
                    "battles":31389
                        }
                        },
           "last_battle_time":1600087522
                 }
       }
}
```

How could I deserialize this JSON containing a number? I tried to use following guide ([Deserialise JSON containing numeric key with Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851185/deserialise-json-containing-numeric-key-with-json-net))

```
public class MetaGetPlayerStats
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
    }

    public class RandomGetPlayerStats
    {
        public int damage_dealt { get; set; }
        public int wins { get; set; }
        public int hits_percents { get; set; }
        public int battle_avg_xp { get; set; }
        public int battles { get; set; }
    }

    public class StatisticsGetPlayerStats
    {
        public RandomGetPlayerStats random { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountGetPlayerStats
    {
        public int global_rating { get; set; }
        public StatisticsGetPlayerStats statistics { get; set; }
        public int last_battle_time { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Dictionary<int, AccountGetPlayerStats> AccountInfoStats { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetPlayerStats
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public MetaGetPlayerStats meta { get; set; }
        public AccountInfo data { get; set; }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. It saw fields "status" and "meta", but "data" == null [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5l82.png)

Comment: Added an image.

Comment: `data` should be `Dictionary<int, AccountGetPlayerStats>` and not `AccountInfo`, putting it there makes it expect `data.data` path

Comment: maybe this question could be removed since it is just a typo issue, and does not really connected to question name

Comment: Yes. Mustafa helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AccountInfo` is excess. `data` is a dictionary. This will work.

```
public class GetPlayerStats
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public MetaGetPlayerStats meta { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, AccountGetPlayerStats> data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your GetPlayerStats class like this:

```
public class GetPlayerStats
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public MetaGetPlayerStats meta { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Dictionary<string, JObject> AccountInfoStats { get; set; }
        // public AccountInfo data { get; set; }
    }
```

then you can proceed to the logic, follow reference.
[Deserialize JSON with "random" key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425460/deserialize-json-with-random-key)